# Excel Index Match and return "Yes" or "No" If value is present in adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I think I'm over complicating this, but I can't find a solution for this issue.

In Table1, I have a list of job names and if they were processed as Color or B&W. Jobs could be both B&W and Color, just B&W, or just Color.  In a Table2, I need to reference the job name from Table1 and determine if that job was processed in color.

Is there a formula that can match the job name from the Table2 to the job name in Table1 tell me if that job was processed in color? Every formula I've tried results in recognizing only the first value for "Type".

I can't post images, but click here for a simplified Table1:

[image: Table1]

And here for Table2. I need to populate the results in cells B2:B4 in Table2.

[image: Table2]

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise!

Comment: determine if countifs is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `Column B` of **Table 2**:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A2:$A11,$A2,Sheet1!$B2:$B11,"Color")>=1`

You should then be able to drag the formula down to check the remaining cells.

<sup>**NOTE:** the `$A2` reference won't need a sheet reference, but it's referring to `$A2` on the sheet where **Table 2** lives.</sup>

You'll need to update `Sheet1!$A2:$A11` with your actual sheet name where **Table 1** lives and the full column that the data covers (same goes for `Sheet1!$B2:$B11`), but this should work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!